# MongodDB Mongoose Collection.findAndModify Upsert: ture

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to add a basic user-to-user messaging service for users of a NodeJS, Express, MongoDB app.

I have two MongoDB documents for the feature: a 'Messages' document which contains each individual message, and a 'Conversations' document, which will refer to all the 'Messages' which belong to it.

So once a message hits the server, I want to do a findAndModify for conversations belonging to both the sender and the recipient. If such a conversation exists, then update it with the new message. If the conversation doesn't exist, then create it and then add the message.

```
app.post('/messages', function(req, res){
  var message = { // Create an object with the message data
    sender: req.body.sender,
    recipient: req.body.recipient,
    messageContent: req.body.msgCont,
    timeSent: Date.now()
  };
  Message.create(message, function(err, newMessage){ // Add the message to MongoDB
    if(err){
      console.log('Error Creating Message' + Err);
    } else {
      console.log("The New Message " + newMessage)
      Conversation.findOneAndUpdate({ // Find a conversation with both the sender
        $and: [                       // and receiver as participants (there should
        {$or: [                       // only ever by one such conversatoin)
          {"participants.user1.id" : req.body.sender},
          {"participants.user1.id" : req.body.recipient}
        ]},
        {$or: [
          {"participants.user2.id" : req.body.sender},
          {"participants.user2.id" : req.body.recipient}
        ]},
      ]}, {$setOnInsert : {
                            messages : message, 
                            "participants.user1.id" : req.body.sender,
                            "participants.user2.id" : req.body.recipient
                          },
      new : true,
      upsert : true
    }, function(err, convo){
        if(err){
          console.log(err + 'error finding conversation')
        } else {
          console.log("Convo " + convo)
        }
      });
    }
  });
  res.redirect('/matches');
});
```

Adding the message to the database works fine, but something with the Conversation query isn't working. I get a console.log of `Convo null`, so it's not returning an error, but nothing is going into the conversation.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong, I'd be super happy with some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB `findOneAndUpdate` method ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate)) doesn't have the option `new`, it's `returnNewDocument` instead. Also, you're missing the curly brackets out these options

```
{
  returnNewDocument: true,
  upsert: true
}
```